# duplicate repository via github API

Tags: node.js, git, github, github-api

I need to create repositories that contains core-files and single setting file via GitHub API.
The single setting file is generated to each application (single unique file),
The core-files are static files, I need to upload them to each repository.
Is there a way to put the core-files in one repo and just duplicate that repository instead of upload these files everytime?
I am using node.js with octonode module.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> The core-files are static files, I need to upload them to each repository. Is there a way to put the core-files in one repo

You can add that repo as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** in each of your other repos:

```
cd arepo
git submodule add https://github.com/username/core-repo
git add .
git commit -m "Add reference to core repo"
git push
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the rapid answer, is there a way to do it via GitHub API?

Comment: @TalLevi no this is a modification done on a local clone, and then uploaded to GitHub.

Comment: I dont work locally, I need to do it automatically.. is this the only way?

Comment: @TalLevi yes it is. You can work locally. All you need is to clone the repos.